# How to safely cast NumPy array of dtype 'object' to 'str' using numpy.ndarray.astype?

Tags: python, numpy, casting

Not sure why the error below is happening. This is just an example. The long story is I was manipulating numpy arrays of dtype 'object' and wanted to "stringify" some of the integers in it to write to a file. So I used the .astype(str) method but then it truncated some new strings I wanted to add to the array, that prompted my decision to always want to work with dtype = 'object'. So I wanted to do x.astype('str').astype('object') so I could then add more strings without them being truncated.

But I wanted to be safe when I use the NumPy astype function, so I want to always use casting = 'safe'. But it errors out for some reason, why does this happen?

> TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('U') according to the rule 'safe'

Why does it give an error with casting = 'safe' but letting casting be the default value ('unsafe') it *does* work?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                      

In [2]: x = [['abc']]                                                           

In [3]: x = np.array(x, dtype = 'object')                                       

In [4]: x                                                                       
Out[4]: array([['abc']], dtype=object)

In [5]: x.astype('str', casting = 'safe')                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e036b3323cdf> in <module>
----> 1 x.astype('str', casting = 'safe')

TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('<U') according to the rule 'safe'

In [6]: x.astype('str')                                                         
Out[6]: array([['abc']], dtype='<U3')

In [7]:
```

Comment: What version of numpy do you have?

Comment: Numpy version 1.18.1

Comment: I don't follow.  If you already have an `object` dtype, and object is better for your task, why are you trying to convert to `str`?  And if all you are doing is converting is Python strings, why worry about the `safe`?  What's mysterious about 'safe' being more restrictive?

Comment: I suspect that all casting from `object` is considered 'unsafe'.

Comment: @hpaulj The array I'm working with also has other types in it that I want to cast as strings (e.g. ints). The reason I'm worried about 'safe' is that I don't want my strings to be truncated.

Comment: 'safe/unsafe' has nothing to do with the string truncation.  You get the truncation when inserting longer strings into a fixed length string dtype.  I'm not sure what the behavior is when concatenating.

Comment: Oh what does safe/unsafe do then?